# Determine what is the time complexity in my code?

Tags: c

I cant seem to figure out what it the time complexity in my function below, the function suppose to count how many integer values holds the value 1 in a row in and determine which row has the most 1's and return that row index number to main.

I thought maybe it would be O(N*logN) since it holds a for loop and a while that decreases itself by half each time.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int func(int mat[][6], int n, int m);
void main()
{
    int mat[][6] = {
    { 0,0,0,1,1,1 },
    { 0,0,1,1,1,1 },
    { 0,1,1,1,1,1 },
    { 0,0,0,0,0,0 },
    { 0,0,1,1,1,1 } };

    printf("max number of value 1 in row: %d", func(mat, 5, 6));

}

int func(int mat[][6], int n, int m)
{
    int i, low, mid, high;
    int ones = 0, maxOnes = 0, index = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        high = m - 1;
        low = 0;
        while (low <= high)
        {
            mid = (low + high) / 2;
            if (mat[i][high] == 0)
                break;

                if (mat[i][mid] == 0) // IF MIDDLE IS ZERO
                {
                    if (mat[i][mid + 1] == 1)
                    {
                        ones = m - mid - 1;
                    }
                    else
                        low = mid + 1;
                }
                else // IF MIDDLE IS ONE
                {
                    if (mat[i][mid - 1] == 0)
                    {
                        low = mid - 1;
                        ones = m - low - 1;;
                    }
                    else
                        high = mid - 1;
                }
        }
        if (ones > maxOnes)
        {
            maxOnes = ones;
            index = i;
        }
        ones = 0;
    }
    return index;
}
```

Comment: Welcome! What have you thought so far?

Comment: @MicheleDorigatti I thought maybe it would be O(N*logN) complexity since it holds a FOR loop that preform n times and a while loop that decreases itself by half each time.

Comment: Do you know that after there is a 1 in a row, all subsequent values are also 1?  If so, then the binary search on a row makes sense (especially if the rows are bigger than just 6 elements), and you'd have an O(N•logM) time complexity (N corresponding to `n`; `M corresponding to `m`).  The binary search on each row is O(logM); you have N rows to process.

Comment: @phonetagger I have edited the code and added the main aswell, I am supposed to write a code that will be at most O(N*LogN) complexity as an exercise.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes the exercise states that each row in the matrix holds first integer value of 0 and afterwards holds the value 1.

Comment: I think the worst case is `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Unrelated to the complexity calculation, I think it would be good to remove the `flag` variable completely and simply break from the while loop when you know the number of ones. And move that entire while loop out to a standalone function that simply counts and returns the count of ones in a 1D array (a row). The code would be simpler and would read better.

Comment: @S.S.Anne Could you explain why?

Comment: Well, there's a function that loops over [0,*n*) and then another that loops over essentially the same thing and if `high` and `low` are never modified then it's one iteration over [0,*n*) for every iteration of [0,*n*).